# How to Open a Closed UDP Client?

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I send some bytes on a specific port and listen on the same port :

```
udpBroadcast = new System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient(2333); // local binding
udpBroadcast.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
   SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
udpBroadcast.Connect("255.255.255.255", 2333);
udpBroadcast.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
udpBroadcast.Close();

udpResponse = new System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient(2333); // local binding
udpResponse.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
   SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

BeginAsyncReceive();
```

The problem is that I need to re-broadcast (for the other end sends me updates) but then I have an `ObjectDisposedException` on udpBroadcast.
I understand `Close()` disposed it but then I found no way to have it Opened.
Trying to recreate (new) udpBroadcast did not help.
Thanks
John

Comment: Lose the `Connect` call, UDP is a connectionless protocol.  You can specify the destination address when you call [`Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82dxxas0.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to flush the data as well as sending it before closing and trying to re-open.This has caused me issues in the past before.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i used this pattern :

```
using (var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp))
{
    var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
    socket.Bind(endPoint);
    using (var client = new UdpClient() {Client = socket})
    {
        var destinationIP = IPAddress.Broadcast;
        client.Connect(destinationIP, port);
        client.Send(bytes, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

which i found at
http://snipplr.com/view/28192/bind-a-socket-including-udpclient-and-tcpclient-to-a-local-network-interface-card-nic/
It works